# How to prove that the given sphere is perpendicular

Tags: partial-derivative

Given the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=ax, x^2+y^2+z^2=bx.$ How to prove that the given sphere is reciprocically normal.

My attemp is:

I find:
$f_x(x,y,z)=2x-a,f_y(x,y,z)=2y,f_z(x,y,z)=2z$

$f_x(x,y,z)=2x-b,f_y(x,y,z)=2y,f_z(x,y,z)=2z$

but i dint know how to continue

Comment: Why are they orthogonal? May be you wanted to say $by$ instead of $bx$ for the second sphere?

Comment: the first and the second sphere is reciprocically norma

Comment: Please edit your question to define "reciprocally normal" since it isn't coming up in my first Google search.